# Read the URL part after # hash with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, url, redirect, hash

I have a URL like this

```
http://www.domain.com/#movies
```

The url is redirected after an authentification filter to

```
http://www.domain.com/login#movies
```

Which contains a login form, I want to redirect the user, after login successful,  back to

```
http://www.domain.com/#movies
```

Or at least read the part after the hash to see the original requested URI.
I have to mention that the hash has something to do with ajax, to load only what changed in the page, this is done by a front-end developer and I'm the back-end developer.
I tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` and `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URL']` but neither worked.

Comment: You can't.  That fragment is not sent to the server.  Consider using a query string `?movies` or `?redir=movies` or something. Possibly have the front-end developer set a cookie that you can read with `$_COOKIE`.

Comment: You could get the part of the URL after the hash via javascript and pass it as a variable in your AJAX request. Something like that:
var ajax_url = '/example.php?test='+window.location.hash.replace('#','');